# How to read a value of a key from JSONstring

Tags: java, json

Below is the json data:

```
"headers": [
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Tue, 13 Mar 2018 12:44:55 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-encoding",
              "value": "gzip"
            },
            {
              "name": "last-modified",
              "value": "Tue, 06 Mar 2018 20:15:30 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "Apache"
            },

            {
              "name": "vary",
              "value": "Accept-Encoding"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "text/html"
            },
            {
              "name": "status",
              "value": "200"
            }]
```

my requirement is to capture date, content-encoding, last-modified, server and status from the above json using java

i am using json-sample-1.1.1 version

can some one please assist how to get these values

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you prefer Java 8 you can use it by this way.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)parser.parse("{\"headers\":[{\"name\":\"date\",\"value\":\"Tue, 13 Mar 2018 12:44:55 GMT\"},{\"name\":\"content-encoding\",\"value\":\"gzip\"},{\"name\":\"last-modified\",\"value\":\"Tue, 06 Mar 2018 20:15:30 GMT\"},{\"name\":\"server\",\"value\":\"Apache\"},{\"name\":\"vary\",\"value\":\"Accept-Encoding\"},{\"name\":\"content-type\",\"value\":\"text/html\"},{\"name\":\"status\",\"value\":\"200\"}]}");
JSONArray headers = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("headers");
headers.forEach( header -> {
    JSONObject headerJsonObject = (JSONObject)header;
    if(headerJsonObject.get("name").equals("content-encoding")){
        System.out.println(headerJsonObject.get("value"));
    }
    // continue
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array, compare names, and retrieve it's value

```
String contentencoding = null;
JSONArray headers = new JSONArray(yourHeadersJsonString);
for ( int n = 0; n < headers.length(); n++ )
{
    if ( headers[n].name.equals("content-encoding") )
   {
      contentencoding = headers[n].value;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Alex!, but i am getting error at headers[n] as " the type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray "

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("array_name");

then start loop to the size of jsonarray and get the values by using methods like getString("key_name") of JSONObject